# Does Jasper Reports work on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, jasper-reports

Does Jasper Reports work on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't. At least, when I created an application with JasperReports, it would run locally on my machine, but not when I deployed it to the AppEngine. The reason is that JasperReports needs the class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment which is not supported by the AppEngine. Look [here](http://www.jscriptive.org/2009/08/jasperreports-and-google-appengine.html) for details.